# When using PopUpManager to instantiate an mxml component, How can I call a public function of that component to pass the component data?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

Basically I am poping up the following component:

PopUpManager.centerPopUp(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,RegionExperienceDetailPopUp,false));

I need to call RegionExperienceDetailPopUp.generateData(passIntArray);

What is the syntax to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PopupManager.createPopUp returns a reference to the component that you can use.

try this instead.

```
var uiComp : RegionExperienceDetailPopUp = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,RegionExperienceDetailPopUp,false) as RegionExperienceDetailPopUp;
PopUpManager.centerPopUp( uiComp );
uiComp.generateData( passIntArray );
```